# Promises and selectors got me down

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, promise, protractor

I have written a bit of code that is designed to figure out if a user is logged into any site. I don't understand the execution order of the code but I can't see how to fix it. Any insight is much appreciated.

The code:

```
  var login_promises = [];
  var logout_promises = [];
  var toggle_login_promises = [];
  var toggle_logout_promises = [];  var loginStringsExist, logoutStringsExist;
  var string_tally = {loginStrings: 0, logoutStrings: 0, toggle_in: 0, toggle_out: 0}
  var promises = {loginStrings: [], logoutStrings: [], toggle_in: [], toggle_out: []};
  var loginStrings = [  "login",
                        "Login",
                        "LOGIN",
                        "Log in",
                        "Log In",
                        "LOG IN",
                        "log in",
                        "signin",
                        "Signin",
                        "SIGNIN",
                        "sign in",
                        "Sign in",
                        "Sign In",
                        "SIGN IN",
                        "log on",
                        "Log on",
                        "Log On",
                        "LOG ON",
                        "logon",
                        "Logon",
                        "LOGON",
                        "logon id",
                        "Logon id",
                        "Logon Id",
                        "LOGON ID"
                      ];
  var logoutStrings = [ "sign out",
                        "Sign out",
                        "Sign Out",
                        "SIGN OUT",
                        "signout",
                        "Signout",
                        "SIGNOUT",
                        "log out",
                        "Log out",
                        "Log Out",
                        "LOG OUT",
                        "logout",
                        "Logout",
                        "LOGOUT"
                      ];
  var toggleInOutStrings = [  "signin/out",
                              "signin / out",
                              "sign in/out",
                              "Sign in/out",
                              "Sign in/Out",
                              "Sign In/Out",
                              "SIGN IN/OUT",
                              "sign in / out",
                              "Sign in / out",
                              "Sign in / Out",
                              "Sign In / Out",
                              "SIGN IN / OUT",
                              "login/out",
                              "login / out",
                              "log in/out",
                              "Log in/out",
                              "Log in/Out",
                              "Log In/Out",
                              "LOG IN/OUT",
                              "log in / out",
                              "Log in / out",
                              "Log in / Out",
                              "Log In / Out",
                              "LOG IN / OUT",
                            ];
  function login_check() {
  }


  var getStringExistsCount = function(string, type){
    return new Promise(
      function(reject, resolve){
        element(by.linkText(string)).isPresent()
        .then(function(el){
          console.log("ELEMENTS FOUND: " + el)
          if(el){
            string_tally[type] ++;
          }else{
            console.log(string + " NOT FOUND");
          }
          resolve(el);
        });
      }
    )
  }

  var load_promises = function(arr, type){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ") ")// + type + " " + string + "\n" + arr.length)
        promises[type].push(getStringExistsCount(arr[i], type));
        if(i === arr.length - 1){
          console.log(promises[type]);
          resolve();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  login_check.prototype.is_account_logged_in = function(pw) {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject){
        if(pw){
          resolve(false)
        }else{
          load_promises(loginStrings, "loginStrings")
          .then(function(){
            load_promises(logoutStrings, "logoutStrings");  
          }).then(function(){
            Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings);
          })
          .then(function(){
            Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings)
            console.log("LOGIN PROMISES: " + promises.loginStrings.length);
            console.log("LOGOUT PROMISES: " + promises.logoutStrings.length);
            console.log("TOGGLE LOGIN PROMISES: " + promises.toggle_in.length);
            console.log("TOGGLE LOGOUT PROMISES: " + promises.toggle_out.length);
          })
          .then(function(){
            console.log("STRING_TALLY:")
            console.log(string_tally);
            resolve(string_tally.loginStrings < string_tally.logoutStrings)
          });
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

the output:

```
.pw_is_present: false
0) 
1) 
2) 
3) 
4) 
5) 
6) 
7) 
8) 
9) 
10) 
11) 
12) 
13) 
14) 
15) 
16) 
17) 
18) 
19) 
20) 
21) 
22) 
23) 
24) 
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
0) 
1) 
2) 
3) 
4) 
5) 
6) 
7) 
8) 
9) 
10) 
11) 
12) 
13) 
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
LOGIN PROMISES: 25
LOGOUT PROMISES: 14
TOGGLE LOGIN PROMISES: 0
TOGGLE LOGOUT PROMISES: 0
STRING_TALLY:
{ loginStrings: 0, logoutStrings: 0, toggle_in: 0, toggle_out: 0 }
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
login NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
sign out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Login NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Sign out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOGIN NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Sign Out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log in NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
SIGN OUT NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log In NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
signout NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOG IN NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Signout NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
log in NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
SIGNOUT NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
signin NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
log out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Signin NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
SIGNIN NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log Out NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
sign in NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOG OUT NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Sign in NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
logout NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Sign In NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Logout NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
SIGN IN NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOGOUT NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
log on NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log on NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Log On NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOG ON NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
logon NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Logon NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOGON NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
logon id NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Logon id NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
Logon Id NOT FOUND
ELEMENTS FOUND: false
LOGON ID NOT FOUND
```

I have tested this on sites that should have at least one match (i.e. ELEMENTS FOUND: true

Don't know what the deal is.

I am not quite sure how to ask this so if anyone who is able to see anything here would like, I can answer further question regarding the problem.

Comment: Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings) appears to create a promise but you are not doing anything with it. What you should do: ...`.then(() => { return Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings); ).then((arrOfLogoutStrings) => { // something cool here with your array of completed promsies });`

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings)` and `Promise.all(promises.logoutStrings)` aren't going to be much use to you , even if used properly. The two aggregated promises would only follow their respective success paths if linkText is found for *all* strings - which isn't what you want and, realistically, will never happen.

What you want is a promise that will resolve in response to finding a link for *any one* of the strings, therefore you need a `raceToResolve(...)` function (twice). Only then, use `Promise.all()` to aggregate the two races.

Also, `load_promises()` is synchronous, therefore doesn't need to return a promise, and by returning a mapped array from the `load_promises()`, the need for outer vars `login_promises` etc disappears.

You could write :

```
var loginStrings = [.....]; // big array of "login" variants
var logoutStrings = [.....]; // big array of "logout" variants

function raceToResolve(arr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var errCount = 0;
        arr.forEach(function(p) {
            p.then(
                function(val) { resolve(val); },
                function(err) {
                    errCount++;
                    if (errCount === arr.length) {
                        reject(0);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
}

function getStringExistsCount(string) {
    return element(by.linkText(string)).isPresent();
}
function load_promises(arr, successCode) {
    return arr.map(getStringExistsCount).then(function(el) {
        if(el) { return successCode; } // found
        else { throw new Error(); } // not found
    });
}

function login_check() {}

login_check.prototype.is_account_logged_in = function(pw) {
    if(pw) {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    } else {
        var loggedInPromise = firstToResolve(load_promises(loginStrings, 1));
        var loggedOutPromise = firstToResolve(load_promises(logoutStrings, 2));
        return Promise.all([loggedInPromise, loggedOutPromise])
        .then(function(results) {
            var compositeCode = results[0] | results[1]; // bitwise `|` will give 0(indeterminate), 1(loggedIn), 2(loggedOut) or 3(ambiguous).
            return compositeCode === 1; // will return `true` if unambiguously logged in, otherwise false.
            // alternatively, expose the compositeCode itself
            // return compositeCode;
        });
    }
}
```

I omitted everything to do with `toggleInOutStrings`.  Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see that the presence/absence of links of the form "signin/out" will help determine logged in/out status.

Comment: Hey...Thank you for your input. I'll try to plug this in and see how it goes. I have only used protractor's canned methods in the past but my needs have outgrown them. As a side note...toggleInOutStrings will work in much the same way as what I posted except I will be looking for a different kind of input. I just wanted to get the above sorted out before implementing them.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TheCulprit, looking at this again, my code isn't right. I can do better and am working on it.

Comment: Edited, replacing `.race()` (which is effectively "raceToSettle()") with a bespoke `raceToResolve()` function.

Comment: Ahhh. This is starting to make sense. I am just trying to sort out a TypeError that gets thrown after the first raceToResolve call and before the second.  Thanks again. Asynchronous programming can be a bit tricky.